support for indian languages in groff
Do groff or troff support any indian languages like hindi or sanskrit?
I have tried using font-install script to install the fonts which are required but it doesn't work. I have also tried to use -mom macros but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Moreover, clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.  As currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"It does not work" is generally considered to be a very bad problem description.
I use install_font.sh to install fonts. That works on my PC (Linux Mint) for Cyrillic and Greek fonts. You're welcome to try it.
Note: It is not my scripting; I just don't have the source where it comes from.

Although looking at your script I would assume Unicode fonts for Indic scripts will not work. It may be necessary to use legacy pre-Unicode fonts.

The script comes with the disclaimers that "it works on my PC" and that it is not my scripting. When I have time, I will try some hindi or sanskrit font.

The script converts opentype and ttf fonts to other formats that cannot support indic rendering in Unicode. So need a very retro, visual based legacy encoding.
